# Replace bytes in file that mismatch from original file

Tags: c#, arrays, replace, filestream, corrupt

I want to copy the minimum amount of bytes over a network to reduce bandwidth over a VPN. I have an external server to where I want to backup and copy files from my PC to the server. Some files are large (database backups). I do not want to keep copying these GB's every time something changes and I have to re-upload the entire file.

I compare file hashes and if they differ I find the bytes that do not match within the file and replace them. Here is some example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] fileAData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileA.FullName);

    int bufferSize = sizeof(Int64);

    int totalIterations = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileA.Length / bufferSize);
    int remainingBytesLength = (int)(fileA.Length % bufferSize);

    using (FileStream fileStreamA = fileA.OpenRead())
    using (FileStream fileStreamB = fileB.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        byte[] fileABytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        byte[] fileBBytes = new byte[bufferSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < totalIterations; i++)
        {
            if (i == totalIterations - 1)
            {
                // If this iteration is the last iteration, read only the remaining bytes
                bufferSize = remainingBytesLength;

                fileABytes = new byte[bufferSize];
                fileBBytes = new byte[bufferSize];
            }

            // Save the current position before read
            long currentPosition = fileStreamA.Position;

            fileStreamA.Read(fileABytes, 0, bufferSize);
            fileStreamB.Read(fileBBytes, 0, bufferSize);

            // Check and replace bytes if they do not match
            if (!fileABytes.SequenceEqual(fileBBytes))
            {
                byte[] destArr = new byte[fileABytes.Length];
                Array.Copy(fileABytes, destArr, fileABytes.Length);

                // Keep a collection of all the changes to the file
                // We will serialize and send this collection to minimalize bandwidth usage
                changes.Add(new Change
                {
                    Data = destArr,
                    Position = currentPosition,
                    Length = destArr.Length
                });
            }
        }

        // If file B is larger than file A, remove the remaining bytes in fileB
        if (fileB.Length > fileA.Length)
        {
            fileStreamB.SetLength(fileA.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

While this code does work for text files, when I try to run this on larger files, the amount of changes that are picked up equate to the size of the original file.

### Example:

If a file is structured like so:

```
Original file:

Position:   1    2    3    4    5    6    7....
Byte:       A    B    C    D    E    F    G

Corrupted file:

Position:   1    2    3    4    5    6    7....
Byte:       A    B    C    E    F    G    H
```

The code will pick up that the first three bytes are the same (A, B, C).
But when it looks at position 4, it will pick up everything else as being changed after that (in reality all bytes only shifted one position to the left).
I want to detect that the only change is technically position 4 so that I do not have to copy the rest of the bytes over the network.

**Am I taking the right approach by comparing bytes in chunks, or is there a faster/easier way?**

**If a file gets corrupt, will it rearrange the entire file's byte order, rendering this method useless? (I've been testing this by opening an mp4 file in a text editor and removing chunks to simulate a "corruption").**

*Extra note: we use back up proprietary software on a client's server which syncs only bytes that have changed within files so I thought this must be possible.*

Comment: Out of interest, Is there a reason why you're doing this yourself? Personally, I would hash chunks and compare chunk hashes. You can even hash subchunks if a discrepancy is found.

Comment: @john Funny you should say that. While waiting for an answer I though of hashing chunks. But that means if a change has been found at the beginning of the file, all preceding hashes would be different, meaning I'd have to replace the rest of the file. I'm doing this because I believe this could be used in other projects that are bandwidth intensive and because I enjoy this kind of stuff :)

Comment: Perhaps you can look at how [rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/576035/does-rsync-inplace-write-to-the-entire-file-or-just-to-the-parts-that-need-to/576217) does it.

Comment: For your scenario of needing to detect that "D" was simply deleted vs. the entire rest of the file changed, that sounds like something text diff tools are good at. I don't know if any provide an API to expose a set of diffs given two input files but it might be a starting point.

Comment: I took the easier root and went with [octodiff](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff). It uses a simple few commands to generate a delta file which I now use to patch the file on the server.